# How to convert a String of Integers to an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion

I try to parse a textfile which has lines which look like the following:

`@KEY,_,0,1,2,_,4,5,6, ...`

The `@KEY` is just an identifier in the beginning while the following numbers are my data which I want to store in an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

I have a metadata class which contains the arraylist in which I want to insert there integers:

```
class MetaD {
    public List<Integer> key1, key2, key3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

I parse the textfile line by line; when the line starts with `@KEY`, I want to add the elements to the `key1` list. If there is an `_`, it should be replaced with an empty value:

```
    if(line.startsWith("@KEY")){
        metaObject.key1 = Arrays.asList(line.replace("@KEY,", "").replace("_", "").trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    }
```

I found out that this does not work with `ArrayList<Integer>`. `key1` has to be of the type `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Object>` to make it work.

Is there a way to convert Integers in the same way?
If not, my idea would be the following:

- Convert everything to an `ArrayList<String>`
- Iterate every item of this new `ArrayList` and convert it with `Integer.parseInt()` into an Integer.
- Adding this new Integer to my `ArrayList<Integer>`

Would there be a more efficient or better way to archive my needs?

---

**Edit:**
Since Tunaki wrote in the comments, that my idea will probably be the only possible way I tried to do the following:

```
    if(line.startsWith("@KEY")){
        List<String> channelTemp =  Arrays.asList(line.replace("@KEY,", "").replace("_", "1").split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        channelTemp.forEach(item -> metaObject.channel.add(Integer.parseInt(item)));
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

Unfortunately, this throws a `NullPointerException` in the third line here and I don't have a clue why. I replaced `_` with `1` for testing purposes to avoid a `NumberFormatException`. When I print out every object in the lambda function instead of adding them to my `ArrayList<Integer>`, I can see that all items have an Integer value. So why do I get an exception here?

Comment: Your idea is pretty much the only way to do it. If you're using Java 8, you could simplify this with Stream operation. You should use `Integer.valueOf` though as it will directly create an `Integer` with no boxing involved (`Integer.parseInt` returns an `int` not an `Integer`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're almost there I'll give you a hand.

```
String line = "@KEY,_,0,1,2  , _,4,5,6,";
List<Integer> collect = Arrays.stream(line.replaceAll("@KEY|_", "").split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect);
```

#### EDIT

To obtain the `null` you can alter the mapping process like:

```
List<Integer> collect = Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
        .skip(line.startsWith("@KEY") ? 1 : 0)
        .map(String::trim)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .map(s -> "_".equals(s) ? null : Integer.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that filter out every empty values? This is pretty bad for me because I want to store those data in a database and this are my columns (where some values can be NULL). But I think I can use your answer for my purposes, I just have to replace `""` with `-1` or similar. Thanks :)

Comment: Follow-up question: Since `ArrayList` allows an element to be `null`, is it possible to replace `_` with Java's `null`? Something like `.replaceAll("_", null)` does not work.

Comment: @Drudge here is a possible pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, your answer works like a charm! Is there a reason why you replaced `.replaceAll` by `.skip`? And could you explain to me what exactly `.collect(Collectors.toList())` does? That's the only part of your code which I do not understand.

Comment: @Drudge Because regex are pretty expensive. So there is no need to replace chars instead I can say if the String starts with `@KEY` then skip the first entry. `Stream::collect` is used to gather the objects in the stream into a specific data structure and in this case it was a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put in list of Integer a String:

```
metaObject.key1 = Arrays.asList(line.replace("@KEY,", "").replace("_", "").trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Here `line.replace(...)` and `trim()` return a `String`, and `split(...)` returns a `String[]`.
Therefore `Arrays.asList(...)` returns a `List<String>` here, that's not compatible with your definition of `key1` (`List<Integer>`).

Yes, you can convert it to `List<Integer>` by call `Integer.valueOf(...)` or `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

But I would recommend to

1. Use a new instance of List instead of `Arrays.asList(...)` because the latest one will produce an unmodifiable collection. Sometines it's not what you want :)
2. Use something less specific than your own text format. What about JSON? There are a lot of libraries to simplify parsing/storing of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should split your string with ",", then you try if your each String is an integer or not with an isIntegerMethod. If it is an integer, you can add it into the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "@KEY,_,0,1,2,_,4,5,9";
    String [] strArr = str.split(",");
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String string : strArr) {
        if (isInteger(string, 10)) {
            intList.add(Integer.valueOf(string));
        } else {
            System.out.println(string + " is not an integer");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(intList.toString());

}

public static boolean isInteger(String s, int radix) {
    if(s.isEmpty()) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(i == 0 && s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            if(s.length() == 1) return false;
            else continue;
        }
        if(Character.digit(s.charAt(i),radix) < 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```